# Histogram of how many times a value appears in a dataset

Tags: r, histogram

Imagine the following very simple dataset:

```
Variable
A
B
B
C
D
D
D
E
F
F
F
```

What I'm trying to get is a histogram of the frequencies of how often those values appear. If you just run hist() on that data, you'll get the count per value, but what I really want is something like:

```
+
+ +
+++
123
```

But, you know, not ASCII art. Mainly, that it collapses the dataset down from variable specific frequencies to saying "Three values appeared once, one value appeared twice, and two values appeared three times."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a nested call to `table`. Here's an example using a variable from `iris`:

```
> table(iris$Sepal.Width)    
  2 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9   3 3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5 3.6 3.7 3.8 3.9   4 4.1 4.2 4.4 
  1   3   4   3   8   5   9  14  10  26  11  13   6  12   6   4   3   6   2   1   1   1   1 
> table(table(iris$Sepal.Width))
 1  2  3  4  5  6  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 26 
 5  1  3  2  1  3  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Calling `table` once tells you how frequently each value appeared, calling `table` on that table then gives you the frequency of different counts. You can then make a `barplot` of the second table to visualize that result:

```
barplot(table(table(iris$Sepal.Width)))
```

[image]

Note: In general `hist` is for summarizing a continuous variable (in specified numbers or sizes of "bins"), whereas `barplot` is for displaying counts.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `table`, to tablulate all your data, and then `hist` on that, using your desired breaks etc:

```
hist(table(Variable))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result using the `descr` package. The code below

```
require(descr)
data("mtcars")
# Get the plot
freq(mtcars$gear, plot = TRUE)
```

would give you this chart:
[image: Histogram - Freq.]

Comment: This appears, as my comment to @HongOoi, to keep the plot value-specific. I'm actively trying not to do that.

Comment: @Fomite how about `table(mtcars$gear)`, it would give you the required figures.

Comment: However, using the first column of the data that comes out of this, and making a histogram of *that* does work...

Comment: @Fomite it would give you the same results as the `table` command, the option `graph = TRUE` simply plots them. I'm guessing that the chart you are looking would be similar to `hist(table(mtcars$gear))`. `freq` command produces a `freqtable` that has total and some other stuff you may not need.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a stem-and-leaf plot, which can be obtained with `stem`.

Comment: The problem is the stem and leaf plot is recording the frequency of each variable. What I'm looking for is "3 values appeared 1 time, 1 value appeared twice, two values appeared three times..."